# Pipe commands at each xargs pass

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

Lets say I have this :

```
echo '/dev/sd'{a..d} | xargs -n 1 lsblk $1
```

But now I want to pipe each pass of the xargs as for instance :

```
echo '/dev/sd'{a..b} | xargs -n 1 lsblk $1 | tail -n +2
```

Now, that does not work obviously, because the pipe is applied to the entire xargs commands. So I might try this :

```
echo '/dev/sd'{a..b} | xargs -n 1 bash -c "lsblk $1 | tail -n +2"
```

But the problem is that now *$1* has no value inside of the shell.

How can I over come this? Or basically, How can I pipe the execution being done by xargs at each pass?

Comment: You need to pass the parameter to the shell, like so I believe: `echo '/dev/sd'{a..b} | xargs -n 1 bash -c "lsblk $1 | tail -n +2" {}`

Comment: Unless `echo /dev/sd/{a..b}` is just a place holder for some other command, I wouldn't bother with `xargs` at all here. Just use a loop: `for f in /dev/sd{a..b}; do lsblk "$f" | tail -n +2; done`. (Even if it *is* a placeholder, there's probably still a way to avoid `xargs`.)

Comment: You may use: `xargs -I {} bash -c 'lsblk "$1" | tail -n +2' - {} < <(printf '%s\n' '/dev/sd'{a..d})` but keep in mind that it will spawn `bash` subpricess for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the report you are seeking:

```
find /dev/sd? -print | xargs -n 1 lsblk | egrep '^NAME|^sd'
```

The output on my system with only sda looks like:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   64G  0 disk
```